Using Neyman-Pearson Lemma to Find the Power of Test
Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from a population with a normal distribution $N(\mu, 1)$, where we know that $\mu = \mu_0$ or $\mu_0 + 1$. Consider the hypothesis test $H_0 : \mu = \mu_0$ against $H_1 : \mu = \mu_0 + 1$.

Use Neymann-Pearson lemma to find the critical region with significance level $\alpha$.
Find the power of test give $n=16$ and $\alpha = 0.05$.

What I have obtained from 1) is that, the critical region is $C = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n):\bar{x}_n \geq \mu_0 + \frac{z_{\alpha}}{\sqrt{n}}\}$. So, the next step I stuck is
\begin{align*}
\text{Power} &= \mathbb{P}(\text{reject  } H_0 | H_0 \text{  false}) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(\bar{x}_n \geq \mu + \frac{z_{\alpha}}{\sqrt{n}} | \mu = \mu_0 + 1 \right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\bar{x}_n - (\mu_0 + 1)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} \geq z_{\alpha}\right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq z_\alpha\right) \quad \text{where  } Z \sim N(0,1). \\
&= \ldots
\end{align*}
Here, If I replace $n=16, \alpha = .05$, I got the Power of test = $\mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq z_{0.05}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq 1.645\right) = 0.05$. Are there any step(s) I made a mistake? Because I and my friend got different answers, he got $\mathbb{P}\left(Z \geq \sqrt{n} + z_\alpha \right)$.
